# 'this' in arrow functions vs non arrow functions in an object literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the following code, in the object literal for obj1, I would assume that the 'this' in both functions would refer to obj1, but in the fat arrow function, it does not.  Can someone explain why?  I would have assumed that the functions would either be equivalent or that in the fat arrow function, 'this' would be defined lexically as obj1.

```
var obj1 = {
  name : 'name1',

  standardFunction : function() {
    console.log(this.name);        //  Refers to obj1
  },

  fatArrowFunction : () => {       //  Refers to the global object
    console.log(this.name);        
  }
}

obj1.standardFunction();
obj1.fatArrowFunction();
```

Comment: `this` *is* resolved lexically. I.e. it refers to the value of `this` of the environment where `obj1` is defined. And there, `this` doesn't refer to `obj1`.

Answer (score 5):

By definition arrow functions behave differently than the traditional ones. A function defined with `() => {}` syntax inherits context from the outer scope.